# subtraction of prime zeros from an alphanumeric field

Tags: sql

Good evening ,

I have an alphanumeric field and I want after the letters to subtract the zeros that it has

my base is azure and my field is a bit like that, the number is 10 digits but I want to subtract the zeros to make it smaller in report. my field is SALDOC.RELDOCSDATE DEAP0000013169 3/12/2021

Comment: Add some more sample data, and also _specify_ the expected result. (E.g. GFRE005020, GFE000506E8.)

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The answer might use product specific functions.)

Comment: Presumably you've investigated the available string functions, what have you tried?

Comment: FYI "subtract" is a math operation, like 7-3==4. Do you want to *remove* (all? specific?) zeroes (or *replace* with empty string)?

Answer (score 0):

If your database support `REGEXP_REPLACE`, then you may try:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('GFRE000005268', '([A-Z]+)0*([1-9][0-9]*)', '\1\2')
```

Here is a [MySQL demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f287300d8a818e1c73578a5a05c9e0f1).  The actual syntax on your database might be slightly different.

Answer (score 0):

It would depend on the requirement.
You can use this if you are sure that there is always just 4 letter prefix.

This would just convert the numbers to INT to remove those zeros from the start.

```
SELECT CONCAT(LEFT('GFRE000005268',4),CONVERT(int,(REPLACE('GFRE000005268',LEFT('GFRE000005268',4),''))))
```